# How to make My rss reader display 10 feed then on clicking next display another 10 and so on

Tags: php, xml, rss, feed, rss-reader

how to make My rss reader display 10 feed then on clicking next display another 10 and so on 
my code is :

```
<?php 
$html = ""; 
$url = "http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstorie... 
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){ 
$title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title; 
$link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link; 
$description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description; 
$pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate; 

$html .= "<a href='$link'><h3>$title</h3></a>"; 
$html .= "$description"; 
$html .= " 
$pubDate<hr />"; 
} 
echo $html;
?>
```

---

when is increase for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) this then the results also get increased but are show in a same page i want to know how to make it show only 10 feeds then when user click net the next 10 are shown and previous 10 are hidden

Comment: `for($i = $_GET['pos']; $i < $_GET['pos'] + 10; $i++) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way to do that is to paginate with [`LimitIterator`](http://php.net/LimitIterator) over a [`SimpleXMLIterator`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLIterator) specifying the page number and the size of each page:

```
$url = 'http://news.yahoo.com/rss/world/';
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url, 'SimpleXMLIterator');

$page = 2;
$size = 10;

$items = new LimitIterator($rss->channel->item, ($page - 1) * $size, $size);

printf("Page #%d:\n", $page);
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo ' * ', $item->title, "\n";
}
```

Exemplary page 2 from right now:

```
Page #2:
 * Air raids on rebel areas near Damascus, Kurds advance: NGO
 * Author Yasmina Khadra to run for Algerian president
 * Fugitive eco-activist says granted Australian visa
 * Egypt family feud kills 10: police
 * French say 2 journalists killed in north Mali
 * Burnley held as Leicester close on leaders
 * Dundee United denied famous win as Celtic snatch point
 * Fire breaks out in Saudi prison, riots and gunshots reported
 * RFI: 2 French journalists kidnapped in north Mali
 * Los Angeles airport partly closed as shooting probe continues
```

This is plain-text only output, but I assume you can see in the example how it works and that it is easy to adopt for HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

You need a $page variable to store and send via link information about current page number.
then you can loop like this.

> $page = 1; 
>   $itemsPerPage = 10;
>
> $start = ($page-1)*itemsPerPage ; 
>   $max = $page * $itemsPerPage ;
>
> for($i = start ; $i < max; $i++)